# File Writing Class

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I was thinking of creating a Class that use a TDictionary to store the results or rather Tstreams until all parts between have been written. In this way, no matter in which arrangement you add the results, in the output, all of them will be arranged. Well, basically, I'm trying to store output Streams of a process in memory and then write it into a filestream. As the time taken by the process differs, so I need this class.

```
procedure HandleOutput(OutHandle: TObjectDictionary<Integer, TStream>;
  Position: Int64; Outstream, mystream2: TStream);
var
  NextPosition: Int64;
begin
  TMonitor.Enter(OutHandle);
  try
    if NextPosition = Position then
    begin
      mystream2.CopyFrom(Outstream, 0);
      Inc(NextPosition);
      while OutHandle.TryGetValue(NextPosition, Outstream) do
      begin
        mystream2.CopyFrom(Outstream, 0);
        OutHandle.Remove(NextPosition);
        Inc(NextPosition);
      end;
    end
    else
      OutHandle.Add(Position, Outstream);
  finally
    TMonitor.Exit(OutHandle);
  end;
end;
```

Above is my attempt to do it, but does quite seem to work, can ya please help me with this?

Comment: You need to read [mcve], assuming you mean "**doesn't** quite seem to work".

Comment: Hard to know how this fits into the rest of your code. Or why you used a dictionary rather than an array. Or what is not working. Why not debug your code? Have you learnt to debug yet?

Comment: And in Delphi, if you consider all those who have to use something like gdb, debugging is a nice experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code accesses `NextPosition`, but I can't see that it is initialized before it is used the first time. That is *undefined behaviour*, because the value of `NextPosition` can be anything. That also makes it very likely that your `if` condition is `False` and the main part of the function is never run.

If you want to store `NextPosition` between function calls, you'll have to make it a global variable, or, in this case, I assume it is better if you make it a `threadvar`. But even then, you will have to initialize it before the first time you use it (i.e. before you call the function for the first time).

If your code is a method of a thread, you can also make `NextPosition` a private member of your thread, of course.

#### By the way:

It looks as if your values of `NextPosition` are consecutive. Then it would make much more sense to use an indexed type, like a `TArray<TStream>` or `TList<TStream>`, to store the streams. These don't have to hash and search an entry, they are direct access. A `TDictionary<Integer, TStream>` seems inappropriate if the keys are `Integer` **and** consecutvive consecutive.

---

*For what it's worth: "Run code snippet" is, AFAIK, meant for languages like JavaScript (or whatever the real name is -- ECMAScript?) that can run in a browser.*

Comment: Even after initiating the `NextPosition` I am not able to make it work, I mean it works, but the arrangement is still a problem